# How do I open a new tab through a Chrome extension background page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension that uses `sendMessage` from the `popup.js` to the background page, and when the `background.js` receives the message it is supposed to open a new tab with a URL. The message sends OK, but the new tab never opens. So how could I get it to open on the users' browser from the background page?

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.urls)
    chrome.tabs.create({url: msg.urls[i]});
})
```

Comment: what version is your manifest? is the chrome.tabs in there too?

Comment: Yes, I have the tabs permission, and I'm using manifest version 2.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out my issue, I was just doing something wrong with the for loop that opened the tabs. The tabs can open from the background page :)